# Oracle OCCI stmt.setTimestamp insert TIMESTAMP(6): microseconds always 0

Tags: c++, oracle, timestamp, occi

*UPDATE: The "fraction of a second" parameter to `Timestamp`'s constructor actually takes nanoseconds... I guessed it was hundredths of a second and my low values were rounded away.  Question left for reference....*

I'm struggling with Oracle's C++ library - OCCI.  Summarily:

- creating `Timestamp` objects and verifying they're good to hundredths of a second (though I'd like more!)
- using `stmt.setTimestamp` then `executeUpdate()` to insert into a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column which should preserve microseconds
- selecting the row in Oracle SQL Developer: the sub-second component is always 0-ed e.g. `14-JUL-11 06.03.27.000000000`.

### Problem

I need subsecond precision - hopefully microseconds!  We've put a lot of work into capturing that precision in our servers and need (at least some of) it for analysis.

### Details

I create a `Timestamp` from year/month/day hour/minute/second/millisecond, reducing the last to hundredths of a second as that seems to be what the constructor supports.  *(No Oracle documentation I can find specifies the interpretation, but in a `fromText` example "xff" clearly corresponds to a ".##" hundredths suffix in the value to convert.  What's the point of `TIMESTAMP(6)` supporting 6 decimal places if you can't insert them?)*

```
oracle::occi::Timestamp temp =
    oracle::occi::Timestamp(_env, year, month, day,
                            hour, minute, second, millisecond / 10);

// re-extract the broken-down time from temp to prove it's stored successfully
int ye;
unsigned mo, da, ho, mi, se, fs;
temp.getDate(ye, mo, da);
temp.getTime(ho, mi, se, fs);

return temp;
```

Here, `fs` gets the milliseconds/10 value as expected.

I use this as in:

```
oracle::occi::Timestamp ts;
ts = _pImpl->makeOracleTimestamp(p->ATETimeStamp);
stmt.setTimestamp(11, ts);
```

Where field 11 is a `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

Selecting the row in Oracle SQL Developer, the other parts of the timestamp column are correct but the sub-second component is 0-ed ala `14-JUL-11 06.03.27.000000000`.

Any insight much appreciated!

(If relevant, using MSVC++ 2005, Oracle 10.2.0.4 sdk, SQL Developer 3.0.04 - please ask if something else might be relevant).

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the "fractional seconds" field is nominally in nanoseconds rather than hundredths.  I wish Oracle would say that in their documents!  I say nominally because if it really preserved the least-significant digits then the hundredths values I had would have appeared as a number of nanoseconds and I might have immediately guessed at the problem - instead it seems values < 100 nanoseconds are lost anyway (and perhaps bigger - I haven't probed the cut-off point).

Thanks to anyone who had a look at the question or tried some research / investigation.

Comment: I will sing praises to your name forever more! I just spent 2 hours debugging this, until I came across this post again.  I even upvoted this 6 months ago, I had just forgotten about this quirk that is nowhere mentioned in the (terrible) OCCI documentation.  Thank you!

Comment: @Johann: you're most welcome - glad it helped - wish I'd got away with only 2 hours of frustration ;-).  Thanks Oracle! O_o